# Gradle composite build cannot find included project dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to set up a composite build. The current structure is

```
projectA
  -build.gradle
  -settings.gradle
  -app
    -build.gradle
projectB
  -buid.gradle
  -settings.gradle
  -sdk
    -build.gradle
```

I need to use projectB as a dependency in projectA, however, projectB still needs to function as a standalone project.

Here's what I have currently

ProjectA settings.gradle contains

```
includeBuild('../projectB')
```

ProjectA build.gradle contains

```
group "com.example"
```

projectA:App build.gradle contains

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.example:projectB'
}
```

projectB build.gradle contains

```
group "com.example"
```

However, when I try to build projectA, I get the error:

```
Could not resolve com.example:projectB.
 Required by:
     project :app
```

What am I doing wrong here? I feel like it has something to do with the 'com.example', but I can't figure out what the correct way to reference the included project as a dependency is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not substituting the dependency in project A. You can refer to example 6 in this section: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_build_declaring_substitutions

In your case, you want to modify the settings.gradle file of project A to look something like:

```
includeBuild('../projectB') {
    dependencySubstitution {
          substitute module("com.example:projectB") using project(':projectB')
    }
}
```

This will tell gradle that during the configuration phase, it should replace any dependency on com.example:projectB with project :projectB found in ../projectB.

Having said the above, it looks like you are actually interested in including the sdk module defined in projectB. If this is the case, you can replace `using project(':projectB')` with `using project(':sdk')`